# Initial useState - map array inside useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone i have a qeustion about good practices, it is fine to initialize state with map in condition like this?:

```
   const [items, setItems] = useState(
    someArray ? someArray .map(item => ({ ...item, isActive: false })) : [],
  );
```

Comment: If the array is large, you should use [LazyInitialState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's ok to do, but there is an improvement that you should add. At the moment, your mapping operation is going to occur on each rerender of your function if `someArray` is truthy. `useState()` will ignore anything its passed after the first initial render, so those additional `.map()` operations are wasted. To avoid doing those, you can pass a state [initializer function](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state) into `useState()` which only runs on the initial render, avoiding all the unnecessary calls to `.map()` for any future rerenders of your component:

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState(() =>
  someArray ? someArray.map(item => ({ ...item, isActive: false })) : [],
);
```

You should also be aware that `useState()` only uses the value it's passed on the first render, so if `someArray` changes in subsequent rerenders, your `items` will not change as it will still hold the array it was initially passed when your component was first initialised. To change `items`, you would need to call `setItems()` instead. Alternatively, you may not need to use state at all if `items` needs to update on each render as `someArray` change and instead create a regular variable that you assign the result of calling `.map()`, which you can make more efficient by using [`useMemo()`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useMemo).

Lastly, I would also consider using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) as your ternary condition, as not all [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values have a [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.